# How to perform jquery actions from one .load to other .load

Tags: jquery

I have two divs that are both auto refreshed every few seconds with content loaded using jquery .load()

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){$("#a1").load("a1.php");
    var refreshId=setInterval(function(){
$("#a1").load('a1.php?randval='+Math.random());},10000);$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});});

    $(document).ready(function(){$("#b2").load("b2.php");
    var refreshId=setInterval(function(){
$("#b2").load('b2.php?randval='+Math.random());},20000);$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});});
    </script>


<div id='a1'></div>
<div id='b2'></div>
```

I need the content inserted into div b2 to be able to manipulate the content in div a1 with jquery..

e.g. content loaded into div 1 a1.php

```
<span class="test">Hello World</span>
```

e.g. content loaded into  in div 2 b2.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.test').text('Good Bye cruel world');
});
</script>
```

But this doesn't seem to work ... Hope that made sense .. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, your question doesn't make sense, you you edit it please? BTW, `id` can't begin with a number.

Comment: @gdoron Seriously? I did that pretty much!

Comment: Question updated for you

Answer (score 1):

Your $(document).ready... code is running before the .load() completes because the load is completing at a later time.  This means that when it gets run there is no span with class "test" yet.

You would have to perform the second load after your first load (into a1) has completed.  For this purpose, load will allow you to pass it a function to call when the load completes ([jQuery load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)):

```
$("a1").load("contentLocation.php", null, function () {
  $("a2").load("nextContentLocation.php");
});
```

This would cause jQuery to load content into a1 and, upon completion, load content into a2.

Comment: In that case, loading a new $(document).ready... call after the page has loaded may simply not get run.  Try a self-calling function: `(function () { $('.test').text('Good Be cruel world'); })();` which may not actually be necessary, but is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: This works but when a1,php refreshes first the div is returned to Hello World?

Comment: You must always (as stated in my post) load the a2 content only after a1 has loaded so that the gap between content updates will be as small as possible.  Change your code to only use a single setInterval that makes a call to load to AJAX in a1, and then AJAX in a2 (by providing a callback).